# Error "uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: addSubGridCell"

Tags: jqgrid

I am working with jqGrid-4.4.1 and I am getting the error "uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: addSubGridCell" can any one tell me the fix? I checked for "grid.formedit.js" and it's also present in my jquery.jqgrid.min.js file

Modules:

- grid.base.js
- jquery.fmatter.js
- grid.custom.js
- grid.common.js
- grid.formedit.js

Comment: Share some code, we need to see in what context you are calling the method.

Comment: The `addSubGridCell` method is defined in grid.subgrid.js and it should exist in `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` and `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`. In the most cases one use just `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` (and later `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` in the working solution). In the most cases the error `"uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method..."` exist because of **wrong usage of jqGrid**. For example the wrong list of JavaScript files which you included could be the reason. So you should include the *whole* HTML page which you use.